# wxpython: howto design a BitmapToggleButton

Tags: button, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want a BitMapButton Class with some toggle functionality:
first press ON, OFF next press etc.
This should be visible in the color of the Button.
I tried the following (needs some tiny 'off.gif', 'on.gif' files):

```
import wx

class BitmapToggleButton(wx.BitmapButton):
    """make a Button, inherits wx.BitmapButton, add a toggleState"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, filename1, filename2):
        """Constructor"""
        self.state = False

        self.image1 = wx.Image(filename1, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.image2 = wx.Image(filename2, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()

        #wx.BitmapButton.__init__(self, id=-1, bitmap=self.image2, pos=(10, 20), size = (300, 400))
        self.image1 = wx.Image(filename1, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.image2 = wx.Image(filename2, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()

        self.button = wx.BitmapButton(parent, id=-1, bitmap=self.image1, pos=(10, 20), size = (self.image1.GetWidth()+5, self.image1.GetHeight()+5))


    def OnClick(self, event):
        """does the toggling"""
        if self.state:
            self.state = False
            self.button.SetBitmapLabel(self.image2)
        else:
            self.state = True
            self.button.SetBitmapLabel(self.image1)
        self.Refresh()



class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """make a frame, inherits wx.Frame, add a panel and button"""
    def __init__(self):
        # create a frame, no parent, default to wxID_ANY
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'wxBitmapButton', pos=(300, 150), size=(300, 350))
        #panel to display button
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        #test it
        self.button = BitmapToggleButton(self, 'off.gif', 'on.gif')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.button.OnClick, self.button)
        # show the frame
        self.Show(True)


application = wx.PySimpleApp()
# call class MyFrame
f = MyFrame()
# start the event loop
application.MainLoop()
```

I confess to have some lost track, I have to inherit from BitmapButton class, right, What is wrong?

joh

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Just use `GenBitmapToggleButton`, see wxPython demo for an example (in Custom Controls/GenericButtons).

**EDIT**: Present since at least 2.8.9.1, see [Link](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.buttons-module.html). Have a closer look at the wxPython demo if unsure how to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have wxPython 2.8. There is no GenBitmapToggleButton
or miss I something?

Comment: Regarding availability: Edited my answer. You should use "add a comment" to add comments instead creating an answer (!).